# RTSP streaming and save into mp4 file using VLC

Tags: vlc, rtsp

let say i am having one RTSP url (rtsp://192.168.0.17/mpeg4). the live camera is setup on the machine which relay live video. i am streaming it using vlc player and i am saving it in mp4 file on some location (i.e. c:\temp.mp4).

Now i am opening another vlc player instance and open this file (c:\temp.mp4). but as it is in use and saving live streaming to that file. that will not be played. if if stop the streaming and then played temp.mp4 file then it will play the streamed (saved) video.

Now my requirement is VLC player should also stream and save into temp.mp4 file continuously and at the same time that file should be played in any standard player.

is it possible to do with any option using VLC player that we can do both this things simultaneously.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with VLC powerful output chain method :

```
vlc input_stream --sout '#transcode{options}:standard{options}'
```

paste your current cmdline please